# Popup Search Box and Smooth Scroll To Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble finding what library is used to enable a search box appear from a popup.

Also, I want to make a widget appear when a user scrolls down and this widget, when clicked, will take the user to the top.

But what I'm specifically asking is what library, or similar library, was used in this demo site: http://htmlstream.com/unify/?

As you can see when you scroll down, a really nice widget appears on the lower right and scrolls up smoothly when pressed.

I also really like the search box being a popup (the search icon next to Contact) as it saves a lot of space in the navigation bar.

Does anyone know what libraries or similar libraries that I can use to implement these features on my site?

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice jQuery plugin that makes the 'top of page' dialog come up and scroll you to the top. [backtotop](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/backtotop)

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.